# Append entire jQuery object to html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clone some players inside my `.shuffler` div. Because I attached click-listeners to the `.player` divs I want to append the entire object instead of just their HTML.

When I loop through the code below I do get the correct result when logging `playerClones[j]` in the `each` loop but it doesn't append anything.

Any ideas on how to clone my players and append every player 25 times to my `.shuffler.` without losing the click listener?

```
this.amountOfDuplicates = 25;
var playerClones = [];
this.parentObject.find('.player').each(function () {
    playerClones.push(jQuery(this).clone());
});

for (var i = 0; i < this.amountOfDuplicates; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < playerClones.length; j++) {
        this.parentObject.find('.shuffler').append(playerClones[j]);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/5vwUJ/)

Comment: Please post a fiddle with your markup. or any Demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you use `$(this).clone()`, everything of the object is cloned except the click listener.

It is better if you could declare a function like this and call it every time u clone the object.

```
attachClickToClone = function() {
   $('.player').on('click', function() {
       //to-do-function
   }
}
```

And call it like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.amountOfDuplicates; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < playerClones.length; j++) {
        this.parentObject.find('.shuffler').append(playerClones[j]);
    }
}
attachClickToClone();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Still don't get why I get 8 player divs in my shuffler where there should be 25 * 4 players...

Comment: Couldn't find what is wrong with your coding, and I only get 8 players as well.

Comment: The clones were moved around. I had to clone the clone after appending it :)